# Auto Invoice Number Generation in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an invoice application using laravel 5.2

I want to create automatic invoice numbers incrementing. Meaning,

If i open create invoice page, i should automatically get #0001 so when i save the invoice, under my invoice_number field it will be 0001 then when i am creating another invoice, the controller will check for the last invoice_number in the database and automatically give me #0002.

Any idea on how to do that or something similar??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the last record from the db in descending order.

```
$invoice = new Invoice();

$lastInvoiceID = $invoice->orderBy('id', DESC)->pluck('id')->first();
$newInvoiceID = $lastInvoiceID + 1;
```

This will return the last ID. Then add 1 to it, and display it on the front end `{{ $newInvoiceID }}`.

Possible issue: What if two users are creating invoices simultaneously? Once they save, the numbers will be different if invoice number is a unique identifier.

One option is to create invoices per user.

```
$invoice = new Invoice();

$lastInvoiceID = $invoice->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('invoice_id', DESC)->pluck('invoice_id')->first();
$newInvoiceID = $lastInvoiceID + 1;
```

Comment: that is my controller, how to i go about adding your code?

Comment: public function save_invoice(Request $request)
  {
   $post = $request->all();
   //var_dump($post); exit();
   
   $data = array(
       'client_id' => $post['client_id'],
       'invoice_number' => $post[$this->invoice_number()],
       'date_created' => $post['date_created'],
       'due_date' => $post['due_date'],
       'status' => $post['status'],
       'payment_method' => $post['payment_method'],
       'currency' => $post['currency']
       );
   $j = DB::table('invoice_headers')->insertGetId($data);
   if($j > 0)
   {

Comment: for($i=0; $i < count($post['count']); $i++)
    {
     $datadetail = array(
      'invoice_id' => $j,
      'item' => $post['item'][$i],
      'description' => $post['description'][$i],
      'quantity' => $post['quantity'][$i],
      'price' => $post['price'][$i],
      'item_discount' => $post['item_discount'][$i],
      'total' => $post['total'][$i],
     );
     DB::table('invoice_bodies')->insert($datadetail);

Comment: }
   }
   $datafinal = array(
    'invoice_id' => $j,
    'subtotal' => $post['subtotal'],
    'discount' => $post['discount'],
    'total' => $post['grand-total'],
    'paid' => $post['paid'],
    'balance' => $post['balance']
   );
   DB::table('invoice_footers')->insert($datafinal);
   
   return redirect()->back();
  }

Comment: Wherever the function is that returns the view for creating invoices, put my code there and modify accordingly. Then, make sure to return the invoice number with any other data that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-increment the invoice_number field in your MySQL table (or just use the 'ID' as your invoice_number:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_number NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
)
```

Every time you add an invoice to the table, MySQL automatically assigns it the next number. So if the last invoice in the table is 3, the next one you insert will be assigned 4.

If you want to display the numbers like #0003 and #0004, just query the database for the invoice_number and format the number in PHP.